# Showing a limit f is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If we let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $[a,b]$ such that,

-there exists a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x_0)$ exists
-each $f_n$ is differentiable
-the sequence $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$

How can I prove that the limit $f$ is differentiable and,

$$f'(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f'_n(x)$$

for each $x\in[a,b]$ ??

Comment: $f$ is the limit of the $f_n$? Then you have to assume that the $f_n$ are also convergent. If so, are they only pointwise convergent, or uniformly?

Comment: What do you know about integrals and uniform limits?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг actually, uniform convergence of the $f_n$ on $[a,b]$ follows from convergence at just one point. The theorem is often stated as such in early course of analysis.

Comment: I have done some courses in them just not quite sure how to apply them to this problem

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Oh, I did not know that. Thank you for  pointing this out.

Comment: @user251257 would you be able to help me with my question?

Comment: @suomynonA thanks for the edit, would you be able to help me with my question?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to assume $f_n'$ to be continuous or replace the statement with $f' = \lim_n f_n'$ almost everywhere.

**Hints:**

1. Under the given assumption the fundamental theorem of calculus applies to $f_n$. That is
   $$ f_n(x) = f_n(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x f_n'(t) dt . $$
2. Use a limit theorem to show that the 
   $$ \lim_n f_n(x) = \lim_n f_n(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x \lim_n f_n'(t) dt =: f(x) . $$
3. The fundamental theorem of calculus than yields
   $$ f' = \lim_n f_n' $$
   (almost everywhere).

Comment: for 2) what limit theorem do I need to use?  I am having trouble with this proof, thanks for your submission also

Comment: @user456 there is a theorem about integral and uniform limits...

Comment: I have been looking through my old calculus book but cant find anything, anyways thanks for your help